# How to compare Clients IDs between 2 periods in Google Analytics?

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

On the Google Analytics platform, I want to find out whether the user who visited on 13/08/2020, also visited (Session > 0) another time between 13/08/2020 - Today or not.

I went to the "User Explorer" category and specified 2 periods in the calendar using "compared to". However, after specifying these 2 periods only  10001 rows are given, and other users IDs are missing. Do you know any solution or any other way to measure this kind of thing?

Or is it possible to download all users' data/statistics?
Or even if it's possible to load this data in R through API?

Also, take into account that my Google Analytics is not **GA4**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)'s the way to export the data to BQ, after which you can query it directly or use a proper BI tool for in-depth analysis.

You could still try using the custom reports in UA since it exposes the Client Id dimension there too. But there are oddities about how UA treats this dimension. I've been debugging UA's client ids recently and I've noticed that UA doesn't like filtering and searching through them, though I used the user explorer. Custom reports is a more powerful tool.

Comment: is it possible to create a custom report which will give me the data I mentioned above?

Comment: I'm not sure. If it's possible, I don't immediately see how.